# Which syntax to use to translate in Blade files?

Tags: laravel, localization, laravel-localization

I am using Laravel 8 and I want to translate a website. As I have a lot of translations to do, I will use the "translations strings as key" (please see [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/localization#using-translation-strings-as-keys)).

I can use the following two methods in my Blade files.

```
{{ __('A propos') }}
```

OR

```
@lang('A propos')
```

My question is: what method do you use and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd really prefer using the __ helper function. If you go in-depth then you will find this helper function pretty cool in terms of its functionality and flexibility. Other than the translation string it receives 2 other parameters. One is **replace[]** and other is **locale**.

```
if (! function_exists('__')) {
/**
 * Translate the given message.
 *
 * @param  string|null  $key
 * @param  array  $replace
 * @param  string|null  $locale
 * @return string|array|null
 */
function __($key = null, $replace = [], $locale = null)
{
    if (is_null($key)) {
        return $key;
    }

    return trans($key, $replace, $locale);
 }
}
```

So we can use this function to perform translation using the key and in bonus also to replace the translation with the values passed in **2nd parameter**. Not only that, but we also have the option to specify in which language we need the translation in the **3rd parameter**.

Secondly, we can use this function anywhere in the project either in Laravel Controllers , views etc.

On the other side, we have the blade directive **@lang()**. I couldn't find its definition anywhere in the vendor but I'm sure that you can only use this in your blade templates. Further it has no **replace[]** and **locale** parameter flexibility just like the **__()** helper function.

At the end of the debate, I'll really choose **__()** helper function because it is flexible, reusable and good documented.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Muhammad. And which tool do you use for the translation ?

Comment: Hi @Dom !  I use google translator for translation

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who needs best combo of said approaches (like me), simply use  `@tr(...)` directive, like:

```
@tr('My :app says hello!', ['app' => env('APP_NAME')])
```

But for above to function, in your `AppServiceProvider.php` file (in `app/Providers` directory) do something like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Blade::directive('tr', function ($expression) {
            return "<?php echo __($expression); ?>";
        });
    }
}
```

### PhpStorm

Once the directive is created, enable auto-completion:

1. In IDE Settings, Go to `Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Blade`.
2. There disable the checkbox `Use default settings`.
3. Then switch to the `Directives` tab, and add new directive, with settings:

   - Name: `tr`
   - Prefix: `<?php echo __(`
   - Suffix: `); ?>`